# Connecting Bluetooth Heart rate monitor to Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8, bluetooth

I am currently creating an Windows store app which connects to Bluetooth Low Energy sensors. Before being able to use a device in your app you must pair it with windows. When I try to pair the device in [control panel -> hardware and sound -> add device], it shows the device but as soon as it try to pair it, it gives me the message: Make sure your device is still discoverable. I have been able to pair other device types(Bike speed and cadence sensor).

I know that Windows Phone couldn't connect to heart rate monitors before an update fixed it, so I was wondering if a similar problem exists for Windows 8.1(Desktop). I have been searching for an anwser but I cannot find anything anywhere, I have also been asking for help on the bluetooth developer site and on MSDN, but with no luck.

The device I am trying to pair with is a Wahoo Tickr(Heart rate monitor) on Windows 8.1 64 bit. My laptop has a Intel(R) Centrino(R) Wireless Bluetooth(R) 4.0 + High Speed Adapter.

Comment: I wonder if the TICKR can only pair with one device, and it's already paired with your phone?